# How to change hover color for iconfont icons?

Tags: html, css, hover, icons

Just beginning learning web development.  I understand how to change the hover color for regular links using `.classname a:hover{}` but every variation of that I've tried hasn't worked. I think there's some quirk to my icons because I downloaded them as an iconfont from flat-icon.com and their instructions (given here: http://www.flaticon.com/iconfont-demo/) make it seem like you need to manipulate the flaticon.css file to change any characteristics like the icon color.

Anyway, this is the relevant part of my code:

```
<div class="jumbotron">
  <div class="container" >
    <h4>Family Owned and Operated Since 1978</h4>
    <table>
      <tr class="big-flat-icons">
        <td><a href="services.html"><i class="flaticon-pipe9"></i></a></td>
        <td><a href="testimonials.html"><i class="flaticon-diploma20"></i></a></td>
        <td><a href="about-us.html"><i class="flaticon-man204"></i></a></td>
        <td><a href="contact-us.html"><i class="flaticon-old26"></i></a></td>    
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
```

I tried putting this in my main.css file but it had no effect:

```
.jumbotron .container a:hover{
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #FF00FF;
}
```

I had to manipulate the code inside the flaticon.css file that came with the font to change the icons' size and color when originally putting them on my page so I feel like there must also be something I need to do in here to get the hover color working but I haven't figured it out yet:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: "Flaticon";
    src: url("flaticon.eot");
    src: url("flaticon.eot#iefix") format("embedded-opentype"),
    url("flaticon.woff") format("woff"),
    url("flaticon.ttf") format("truetype"),
    url("flaticon.svg") format("svg");
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}

[class^="flaticon-"]:before, [class*=" flaticon-"]:before,
[class^="flaticon-"]:after, [class*=" flaticon-"]:after {   
    font-family: Flaticon;
        font-size: 100px;
font-style: normal;
margin-left: 20px;
color: white;
}


.flaticon-antique:before {
    content: "\e000";
}
.flaticon-construction3:before {
    content: "\e001";
}
```

Sorry for the long question. Does anyone have any ideas?

If it helps, this is where I have the site I'm working on: http://reagankm.github.io/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think that icon font doesn't receive the hover style properly, but you can try this:

```
.jumbotron .container a:hover i:before {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #FF00FF;
}
```

Comment: It worked!  You're my hero!  I've spent so many hours trying to solve this thing.  Thank you. :]